# cancelling previous requests server side

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, web

In our web application we have the different options the user can choose.

If the user does different selects/options a request is sent to server for each select/operation and response is displayed in the UI.
If the user does multiple operations sequentially all the requests are sent to server separately.
we want to cancel all the previous requests when a new request is received in server side.

Currently we are creating new thread for each request and when new request is received all the old requests for that specific user are cancelled. please let us know if this is right way or if there is a better way.

Comment: If it's about important Request and have been solved, it's a right way. But if it's not been solved yet, better not. Of course, what kind of request it's

Comment: @Suman **If the user does multiple operations sequentially all the requests are sent to server separately.**                            If the above is not your requirement. Restrict the multiple posting at UI. Manual thread handling is not recommended as per servlet specification.

Comment: Its part of my requirement as we dont no when the user will stop the operation the, server should return the result of last operation

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to cancel the request on tomcat, that might be difficult. But, if you are using ajax to submit request to server, you will be able to abort the request at the client side and send a new request. This is all assuming the request is idempotent.

Comment: The problem is to cancel a request that is already running on the server. Ajax only can ignore the server response, not cancel.

Comment: If your server state changes with each call, you are in trouble.